# Was this Cersei's plan?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the *Game of Thrones* season 6 finale, we see King Tommen commit suicide. Meanwhile we see that Cersei already dressed up like the Queen for her inauguration.

---

Before committing suicide, a servant of Tommen said "sorry". **Did the servant send any message to Tommen to commit suicide as per Cersei's plan?**

Well many of you might say that, if Cersei wishes to kill Tommen, then she might allow Tommen to go to the Red Keep but Cersei might think that it will make her a bad person, rather than making Tommen commit suicide.

Comment: Well, she is Cersei Lannister ,she always dresses like a queen. Also  she love her kids more than anything.

Comment: I believe the servant was informing King Tommen about the casualties.

Comment: Your assumption that Cersei "dressed up like the Queen" seems ill-founded at best.  Prior to this episode, [Westeros only had one Queen-regnant](http://iceandfire.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Kings_of_Westeros), and that was a disputed claim.  We never saw what she wore while on the throne. And Cersei herself had been the Queen-consort while Robert Barathean served as King, and she never wore that outfit while she did.  So what makes you believe that black get up was a Queen's dress?

Answer (score 11):

No, Tommen's suicide is not part of her plan. She obviously did not intend to kill her single remaining child, that's why she sent Ser Gregor Clegane to prevent him from going to the Great Sept Of Baelor.

Comment: Then why did she dressed up like a queen ?  One more thing its clear that , Cersei wants to sit in iron throne , how could she seat if Tommen is alive

Comment: @shuvro Time is compressed, events are happening over a much longer time, etc. It's obvious the showrunners play fast and loose with the timing for greater dramatic effect. Don't bother trying to make sense of it, so much of this episode and previous ones just doesn't add up.

Comment: @shuvro I don't think that's her "Queen" outfit, I think that's her "Don't f`**`k with me b`**`ches" outfit, and she considered it equally appropriate for surveying a destroyed crypt as she did for [taking the throne when she had no grounds other than others' fear for doing so](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133237/31938)

Answer (score 7):

She dressed up like a bad-ass - it was her master move, but the only driving force she had outside of her own pleasure was her children.  She expected to eliminate all of the outside influences on Tommen and control him directly.
But it could be she saw him as already dead because he had converted to the Sparrows - I don't think we have a clear answer yet.